# In football, is it offside if an attacker passes backwards but it deflects forward of a defender?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

An attacker passes the ball backwards but it hits a defender and deflects forward to another attacker coming from an an offside position. The attacker gains control, turns and shoots toward goal.
Is the play to be disallowed for an offside pass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there offside when the ball deflects off an opponent?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16200/is-there-offside-when-the-ball-deflects-off-an-opponent)

Comment: In this question the ball is passed backwards so it is different from the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Offside. All what matters is the relative position of ball and receiver (forward) at the time of the pass. The rules do not specify anything about the direction of the pass.

From Law 11 of the FIFA Rules:

> Offside position
>   A player is in an offside position if- he is nearer to his opponents’ goal line than both the ball and the second-last opponent.
>   A player is not in an offside position if he is in his own half of the field of play OR he is level with the second-last opponent OR he is level with the last two opponents

If it is a deliberate pass by the defender however, the forward is not offside.

Comment: may I be enlightened on the reason for the downvote?

Comment: FIFA hasn't had control of the LOTG for years now. We already know the player is in an offside position, so the law cited doesn't help at all. The answer completely ignores the part of the law that tells us what the correct decision is, the keyword is even stated in the question: **deflection**.

Comment: FIFA is not in charge of the football rules? Are you kidding me? Who else then, please enlighten me again? And don't say IFAB, they are in charge of changing the rules. Deflection was only part of the question, the other was about the backward pass.

Comment: IFAB is clearly in charge of the rules, the most recent revision confirms this. In particular, from the introduction itself: *"No alteration to the Laws of the Game can be made by any confederation or national football association (including competitions) unless it has been passed by The IFAB."*. Ignoring that the defender played the ball, with no justification in law provided, makes this answer worthless as a response to a question about whether an offside offence has occurred.

Comment: As I (and you yourself said), IFAB is in charge of *altering* the rules, which are then made public by the FIFA. So the laws of the game from FIFA is a viable source. Second, the rules do not explicitly discuss offside from an opponents pass, since offside only exists for passes from a teammate. So what is left for the referee (and mentioned by me) is to judge whether there is a deliberate play by a defender.

Comment: Again, the keyword: deflection. Again, we are already told the player is in an offside position, and the answer does nothing to determine whether they have committed an offside defence. The laws do explicitly say whether an offside offence occurs from an opponent's pass, so I can only conclude you've not actually read the whole law. Finally, the official source of the laws is the IFAB site, and has been for the last two years. Please go to the IFAB website and use it to improve your answer.

Comment: IFAB has always (at least for the last century) been in charge of the Laws of the Game. FIFA used to publish the Laws, but now IFAB do that directly as well through their website and by publishing copies of the Laws (at [http://theifab.com](http://theifab.com)).

Answer (score -1):

An offside position cannot occur when the ball comes from the defense, the most famous goal that illustrates that is the "The hand of god", the goal was controversial because of a hand play even though Maradona was seemingly offside, the reason he wasn't, is because the ball came from Steve Hodge.

Comment: This is not true. A deflection off a defender does not excuse offside offences.

Comment: This is wrong in almost every respect.